# Can we append similar named columns onto one column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I'm appending multiple text files one one single data frame.  For some reason, which I don't totally understand, the column names change slightly over time, but they are really the same thing.  Here's an example.

```
['ACCEPTANCES_EXECUTED_FOR_ACCT____OUT',
 'ACCEPTANCES_EXECUTED_FOR_ACCT____OUT_1',
 'ACCUMULATED_OTH_COMPREHENSIVE_INCOME',
 'ACCUMULATED_OTH_COMPREHENSIVE_INCOME_1',
 'ALLL_AMT',
 'ALLL_AMT_1',
 'AUDIT_INDICATOR',
 'AUDIT_INDICATOR_1',
 'AVAILABLE_FOR_SALE_SECURITIES',
 'AVAILABLE_FOR_SALE_SECURITIES_1',
 'COMMON_STOCK',
 'COMMON_STOCK_1',
 file]
```

I know that `'ACCEPTANCES_EXECUTED_FOR_ACCT____OUT'` and `'ACCEPTANCES_EXECUTED_FOR_ACCT____OUT_1'` are the same.  Similarly, `'ACCUMULATED_OTH_COMPREHENSIVE_INCOME'` and `'ACCUMULATED_OTH_COMPREHENSIVE_INCOME_1'` are the same.

Is there a way to get the field named `'ACCEPTANCES_EXECUTED_FOR_ACCT____OUT_1'` appended under the field named `'ACCEPTANCES_EXECUTED_FOR_ACCT____OUT'` and then drop the `'ACCEPTANCES_EXECUTED_FOR_ACCT____OUT_1'`?

Or, is it possible that there is a problem with my append?  I think it's just a standard append process.

```
try:
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='\t', skiprows=1) 
    df['file'] = os.path.basename(f)
    all_df[x].append(df) 
except:
    print(f + ' seems to have some bad data points. please check and confirm!')
```

Comment: To clarify, I'm assuming this is part of a loop or something where each file only has one of each column, and all_df is the running appended df, correct? Or are you saying that a single file could have all these 'duplicated' columns, which then need to be stacked?

Comment: Yes,I am looping through a bunch of files in a folder and appending all files with similar names, like this 'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RC0'.  I have'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RC1' and 'FFIEC CDR Call Schedule RC2', etc.  Each file has a date in the name of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two potential solutions: First, if the column order is always identical, you can set the column names before stacking. `df.columns = all_df.columns`.

Second, if the change is always as simple as "_1", and if that substring doesn't appear in any other places, you could sub that out of the column name with a `.replace('_1', '')`. Something along the lines of `df.columns = [x.replace('_1', '') for x in df.columns]`.

Beyond that, you'd probably have to do something fancier with fuzzy string matching.